# yarn/npm is using out of date code inexplicably with mocha and typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, mocha.js, yarnpkg

This is one of the weirdest things I've ever seen. If I invoke my test command manually I get two test results, but if I run the same command in a yarn/npm script it only displays one result. Has anyone run into this before, and how did you fix it? Very bizarre.

I tried deleting my compiled ts and recompiling but no luck.

```
~/g/tally-bot> npm run testt

> tally-bot@1.2.1 testt /Users/ryan/git/tally-bot
> ts-mocha --recursive --exit **/*.test.ts

/Users/ryan/git/tally-bot/util


  bump command
Bumping [test | Global: false] by 1
    ✓ should run a test

creating tables

  1 passing (30ms)

ryan@ryan-macbook-2 ~/g/tally-bot> ts-mocha --recursive --exit **/*.test.ts
/Users/ryan/git/tally-bot/util


  bump command
Bumping [test | Global: false] by 1
    ✓ should run a test

  db-new.test.ts
creating tables
hmm
    ✓ test


  2 passing (39ms)
```

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so turns out it was because my shell environment was different for yarn.

I ran the following to fix it as I use fish for my shell.

`yarn config set script-shell "/usr/local/bin/fish"`